# Web Skype on my website

Tags: javascript, web, skype

I am trying to add skype to my website, so users could call each other from website. So, skype is giving opportunity to do that in two lines of code, unfortunately it is not working

```
<span class="skype-button rounded" data-contact-id="skypeID" data-text="call"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://latest-swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/0.24.37/sdk.min.js">
```

here by adding user's skype id, one user could easily call to another one, but when i am trying to do it, I am getting mistake:

```
GET https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/0.24.37/sdk-run.min.js 404 ()
```

source code of that javascript file is within that link and it openes without problems. And here a link to skype web tutorial

https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol

Comment: You have two different URLS here. The `https://swc.cdn.skype.com/...`  does in fact appear to be a 404.  The`https://latest-swc.cdn.skype.com/...` one is correct.

Comment: All that I am using are only two lines of code, where that mistakes come from?

Comment: Ah, apologies, I understand now; the good url redirects to the bad one if used in a script tag -- I think that may be an error in their tutorial; later in the same page (under "implementation > getting started") they show a different URL that does work: https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js

Comment: thanks, it helped me a lot

Comment: Great catch. I'll see if I can get that fixed in the tutorial.